# Bootstrap responsive navbar works when scaling in browser but doesn't when on my mobile

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have a personal app i've been working on using nodejs, express with jade to build the UI. The site scales file in a browser and all the mobile emulators i've tried. The site is myrecipes.me and the code in question is below.

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top(role="navigation")
  .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
      button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar')
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a.navbar-brand.title(href='#') 
        img(src='/img/myrecipelogo.png', alt='Main Image', height='40px')
    .navbar-collapse.collapse#navbar
      ul.nav.navbar-nav                
        li.dropdown
          a.dropdown-toggle#cocktailList(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
            | Drinks
            b.caret
          ul.dropdown-menu
            li
              a(href='../newrecipe') Add a Recipe 
            li.divider  
              each drink in drinks
                -if(drink.type == 'cocktail')
                  li
                    a.dropCockails(id="#{drink._id}")= drink.name
        li.dropdown
          a.dropdown-toggle#foodList(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
            | Food
            b.caret
          ul#dropFood.dropdown-menu
            li
              a(href='../newrecipe') Add a Recipe 
            li.divider
              each drink in drinks
                -if(drink.type == 'food')
                  li
                    a.dropCockails(id="#{drink._id}")= drink.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have anything in the header to set the viewport?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yes, currently I have "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" and I've also tried "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0".

Comment: hard to debug without seeing the page

Comment: Sorry, I posted it about but didn't make it a link so it kinda disappears. It's can be found [here](http://myrecipes.me)

Comment: The below answer is why there is no meta tag, so thank you helping me realize something odd was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a fix to this issue on [this link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/responsive-theme-not-responding-when-domain-forwarded). I was forwarding the URL using a url-iframe on NameCheap so I could keep the address of my domain visible, but the iframe dumps the meta tag. So redirecting my url with a url-redirect works but then I view see the hosting url once I'm there. Hope this can help someone else with the same problem.